# How can I sell content on the Ubuntu Store

Tags: software-center

In the Ubuntu software center, I often see maganizes.  I am a digital comic book publisher and longtime Ubuntu user. Basically, I would like to make my content available. I see where to submit apps at developer.ubuntu.com, but nothing for content. can anyone assist?
Thanks!
Rodolfo